# PDO prepared statement returning the entire table when data_type mismatch

Tags: php, pdo

I am very new to PHP and while fixing a bug have come across something I can't explain.

The bug was the mismatch between my string `$courseName` and the data_type expecting a `PARAM_INT` instead of `PARAM_STR`.

However the bit I cannot explain, is that when `PARAM_INT` is used the **entire table** `course` is returned from the database.
It makes sense to return no rows, but why every row?

Is this a data conversion error, a null issue, or something else?

---

```
$courseName = "SIR30216";

$courseInfoQry = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM course WHERE courseName = :courseName");
$courseInfoQry->bindParam(":courseName", $courseName, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($courseInfoQry->execute()) {
    // For debugging only
    print_r($courseInfoQry->fetch());
    print_r($courseInfoQry->fetch());
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try `$courseInfoQry->bindParam(":courseName", $courseName, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($courseName));`?

Comment: That is because of string-to-int conversion at the WHERE clause comparison. When the data on one side is a string, and the other side an int, the string is attempted to be "promoted" to a number, which it won't, and becomes 0. So effectively, all rows _will_ have 0 = 0, and thus all match.

Comment: It is caused by `PARAM_INT` effectively performing `CAST('SIR30216' AS UNSIGNED) ` which is converted to `0`, which in-turn `WHERE courseName = 0` causes MySQL to  [automatically cast the data-type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) `courseName` column values to an integer value of `0`.

Comment: @WillB. & Paul T. Thank you so much! That makes sense why it is returning everything. Interesting that the database picks to cast the string to a number and not the other way around

Comment: @PaulT. Thank you! I wrote my reply without giving it enough thought, that is exactly what is happening

Comment: (previous comment edit) But to your example with `courseName = 4`, returns no rows, though correct? ... That's because the promoted courseName to 0 becomes `0 = 4`, so no matches. But if you do `SELECT id FROM course WHERE courseName = 0;`, then all rows will be returned.

Comment: As you have the PHP tag, know that similar conversion handling is done in PHP too. Try the difference of `echo ('united states' == 0) ? 'yes' : 'no';` versus: `echo ('united states' === 0) ? 'yes' : 'no';`, the latter of the two would be the expected result using the strict comparison.

Comment: You can retrieve the warnings from `SHOW WARNGINGS` which will output `Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'SIR30216'` but will still perform the data-type conversions and return all results. To prevent the data-type conversions you would need use `WHERE courseName = BINARY :courseName` which will cause your criteria to be case-sensitive if you use a `_ci` collation.